# What scope when using $.when in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new at this web stuff and I have some calls to the server that look like this

```
$.when.apply($, serverRequests).then(function () {
    // update the UI on the page
    // remove overlay
});
```

So my update the UI on the page part works.  But what I want to do is add an overlay while the server requests are happening.  So I tried adding a method to my serverRequests array with unshift hoping that this would add the overlay, so I later could remove it in the //remove overlay portion.

```
        var addOverlay = function () {
            console.log("--------------");
            console.log(this);
            console.log(_this);
        };
        serverRequests.unshift(addOverlay);
```

In my attempt to try to add an overlay with _this.$el.find("#mypage"), I was running into issues.  So I tried logging things to the screen.  In the above addOverlay() function, I get nothing printed to the screen.  But if I do this:

```
var addOverlay = console.log("hello world");
serverRequests.unshift(addOverlay);
```

This does work.  What's the difference here?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: In first case you're passing reference to a function, in second you're passing `undefined`. Is it the difference you're asking about? PS: if you want to assign a particular scope - you may use `$.proxy()` (or `.bind()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   var addOverlay = function () {
       console.log("--------------");
       console.log(this);
       console.log(_this);
   };
```

is nearly equal to

```
   function addOverlay () {
         console.log("--------------");
         console.log(this);
         console.log(_this);
  }
```

So instead of,

```
     serverRequests.unshift(addOverlay);
```

you need to call the function,

```
    serverRequests.unshift(addOverlay());
```

Also here,

```
var addOverlay = console.log("hello world");
serverRequests.unshift(addOverlay);
```

It logs into console, as you havent created any function, and directly calling `console.log`, so it works.
Here you are logging `hello world` into `console` and then saving the `return` of `console.log` into addOverlay.

Comment: `serverRequests.unshift(addOverlay());` why are you passing `undefined` to be placed in the beginning of the array? You'd rather just call the function instead.